# php printf adds number to output

Tags: php, printf

I wanted to format some output using printf, but it outputs a number after each item for some reason. Any ideas as to why this is and how it could be fixed?

```
$array = array("Mo" => "09:30-19:00",  
          "Di" => "09:30-19:00", 
          "So" => "geschlossen");

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     echo printf("%3s:%15s", $key, $value);
}
```

output

```
Mo: 09:30-19:0019 Di: 09:30-19:0019 So: geschlossen19
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it just because you're `echo`ing a `printf`?

http://codepad.org/1KtxR9JF

```
<?php

$array = array("Mo" => "09:30-19:00",  
          "Di" => "09:30-19:00", 
          "So" => "geschlossen");

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     printf("%3s:%15s", $key, $value);
}

 Mo:    09:30-19:00 Di:    09:30-19:00 So:    geschlossen
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are using `echo printf(...)` rather than just `echo`?

If not, then using this returns correctly (without the 19 being appended):

```
$array = array("Mo" => "09:30-19:00",  
          "Di" => "09:30-19:00", 
          "So" => "geschlossen");

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     echo "$key:$value";
}
```

Comment: Sorry just reread your answer about formatting it using printf.

Comment: ^See MetalFrog's correct answer which is the other way round.