# Why PHP echo printf adds unexpected symbols

Tags: php, printf, echo

I have php code:

```
$searchTitlePersonType = ($isTravelAgency == true ? "tourists" : "persons"); 
var_dump($searchTitlePersonType); // Right behavior
```

The same time, when I try to implement it on my template:

```
<?php
    echo printf( $this->translate("Поиск %s"), $searchTitlePersonType ); 
?>
```

I'm taking different unexpected numbers at the end of string: "tourists33" or "persons27". It's not depend of coding page of string and there is a lot of people who find the way to resolve it - do not combine `echo printf` in one line of code, but here my question about this problem: WHY does it happen?

Links:

[php printf adds number to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849470/php-printf-adds-number-to-output)

[PHP printf adds something after formatted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776231/php-printf-adds-something-after-formatted-string)

Comment: Quoting the accepted answer in your first link: "Isn't it just because you're echoing a printf?"

Comment: ^ I'd say the same. `printf()` returns an integer (length of the string). When you echo it, it will print that integer. http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php In other words: you should use *either* `echo` or `printf()`, but not both!

Comment: "printf" command doesn't need "echo" because it outputs the data itself. Using echo you output result of "printf" command which is the length of the outputted string. You must either remove `echo` or use `sprintf` instead of `printf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing some things here. `echo printf` as a construct does not make sense, since `printf` already prints.

What you are seeing, is that `printf` does its job, and then `echo` prints the result of `printf`, which is the length of the printed string.

So, instead, you can use `sprintf`, which returns the formatted string instead of printing it, or you can skip the `echo` part of your program.